# ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration problematic behaviour

Tags: c#, wpf, config

I have a very strange problem with my WPF application. I am trying to open a regular config file using this method:

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ PATH_TO_CONFIG ]; //which returns a valid path 
s_config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration( fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None );
```

This works fine when you first run the application - it finds the config file in the directory the app .exe resides. - D:\MyApp\bin\Debug\MyConfigFile.conf But when you open another instance of the application by right-clicking on the running application icon in the toolbar, and from the context menu you choose to open new instance then I get a strange behaviour:
The s_config.FilePath now doesn't find my config file, because it is pointing to "C:\Windows\systems32\myConfigFile.exe.config" And this problem only reproduces when the second application is started like this.

Does anybody has an idea what might be the problem?

Comment: I'd think it has something to do with the ConfigurationManager being a static class.

Comment: OK @RoyDictus, but I still need a solution for either how to make those classes work properly or another way to load this config file.

Comment: This requires psychic debugging.  Such a shortcut does not appear by default, you did something to get it added to the taskbar button's context menu.  And got the working directory wrong.  Then exacerbated by you using a relative file path in your code, thus ending up with the default directory that Explorer uses.  Create a reliable full path name by using Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() to find your install directory back.

Comment: Thanks @Hans but I think every working program that has an icon in the task bar on right-click has the option to open another instance of that application(at least in Windows 7). Just try with a clean WPF project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We didn't find the solution to the problem so we worked around it. In case the config file is not found, we used
    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
to get the full path to the config file and to pass is to fileMap.ExeConfigFilename